# Objective C - Safely create a static Boolean?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I want to have a static boolean like in Java. This boolean only created once for the entire class, no matter how many instance it has.

I read some posts here. Some of them are suggesting that in `.m file`, init this variable like

```
static BOOL myBool = NO;
```

and then have a getter and a setter function. But I was told that this is not safe and clean in Objective C. A safer and cleaner way to do this is init static variable in function. But if I init it in a function, like

```
+(Bool)getMyBool {
    static BOOL myBool = NO;
    return myBool;
}
```

In this way myBool will always NO. What if I want to set this boolean afterwards? If I call `static BOOL myBool` again, would it give me the same boolean?

Comment: "In this way myBool will always NO." – you seem to have missed the point of `static`.

Comment: "I was told..." By whom? And in what context?

Comment: The original code is absolutely fine. Whoever told you it's not safe and clean suffers from some object-oriented illness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
+(BOOL)resetBoolOrGet:(BOOL)reset newVal:(BOOL)newValue {
    static BOOL myBool = NO;
    if (reset) {
        myBool = newValue;
    }
    return myBool;
}
```

So, if you want to assign a new value to this boolean, call

```
[MyClass resetBoolOrGet:YES newVal:newValue];
```

If you only wants to get the value of that static boolean, call

```
[MyClass resetBoolOrGet:NO newVal:(either YES or NO)];
```

Comment: `bool` is a typename in C and C++, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: That'll work, but I don't see the point of it all unless you really want access to that BOOL from outside the compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently “not safe and clean” about a global static variable in Objective-C and they are commonly used when appropriate - they are effectively Objective-C's class variables.

See [Setting Static Variables in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979973/setting-static-variables-in-objective-c/15980334#15980334) for one way to write the getter and setter functions you mention.