# What does the class attribute of property mean?

Tags: objective-c, class, runtime

When I look at the header NSObject.h for Objective-C, I find some code like the following but I can't find out the meaning of class as an attribute of property.

```
@protocol NSSecureCoding <NSCoding>
@required
// This property must return YES on all classes that allow secure coding. Subclasses of classes that adopt NSSecureCoding and override initWithCoder: must also override this method and return YES.
// The Secure Coding Guide should be consulted when writing methods that decode data.
@property (class, readonly) BOOL supportsSecureCoding;
@end
```

What does the class attribute mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` attribute is used to declare a *class property*. A class property is shared by all instances of the class, unlike an *instance property* where each instance has its own copy. Class properties where introduced in Xcode 8 and unlike instance properties they are never synthesised and the programmer must write the getter and setter.

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979973/setting-static-variables-in-objective-c) for more details.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.